# How can I amass lard quickly?

Tags: muchi-muchi-pork

As the cornerstone of Muchi Muchi Pork's scoring system, the Lard Meter is extremely important, as it allows you to use your Lard Attack, which creates Medals that are collected for points. However, management of the lard meter is tricky, and it's extremely easy to find yourself out of lard at a crucial moment.

What are the best ways to refill the Lard Meter as quickly as possible if I find myself in a situation where I need a lot of lard, and I need it right now?

In particular, I care most about the 1.01 version of the game.

Comment: What system is this on? I am intrigued.

Comment: Xbox 360 (Japanese, region-free) and arcade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to obtain lard, but there are a lot of little nuances that aren't immediately apparent, and it's easy to accidentally mess things up if you're not careful.

1. Shooting enemies with normal Shot (A button) will produce piggies, which increase the Lard Meter when collected. Airborne enemies will produce parachuting piggies that can be sucked in by flying near them, and ground enemies will produce ground-based piggies that must be picked up manually.
2. Using the Lard Attack (B button) *when the Lard Meter is empty* will shoot out a narrow piercing shot, which generates lots of piggies (more than the A button) from every enemy that it destroys.

   However, you **must** press the A button to switch back to "Shot mode" before you pick up the piggies in order for your Lard Meter to increase; otherwise, you'll just get points. You can tell you're in the right mode if your Options are hovering out to the sides of your ship, rather than sitting behind it.
3. Using a bomb will spawn pigs from all enemies and bullets that it destroys. This can work in an emergency, but it obviously has other side effects, such as potentially destroying a bunch of valuable medal-giving enemies.

Additionally, it's important to realize that your Lard Meter decreases by a large amount (around 30%?) whenever you switch from Lard Attack mode (B button) to Shot mode (A button). While this is necessary to suck in on-screen medals, it's also important to plan around this so that you don't waste a lot of lard unnecessarily.